# Extracting Web Data Using Beautiful Soup (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

in the code sample below, 3 of the 5 elements I am attempting to scrape return values as expected.  2 (goals_scored and assists) return no values.  I have verified that the data does exist on the web page and that I am using the correct attribute, but not sure why results are not returning.  Is there something obvious I am overlooking?

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2 
import datetime as dt
import time
import pandas as pd

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)

player_name=[]
club =[]
position = []
goals_scored = []
assists = []

for p in range(25):
player_url = 'http://www.mlssoccer.com/stats/season?page={p}&franchise=select&year=2017&season_type=REG&group=goals'.format( 
        p=p) 
page = opener.open(player_url).read() 
player_soup = bs(page,"lxml") 
print >>sys.stderr, '[{time}] Running page {n}...'.format( 
        time=dt.datetime.now(), n=p) 
length = len(player_soup.find('tbody').findAll('tr'))

for row in range(0, length):
    try:
        name = player_soup.find('tbody').findAll('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Player'})[row].find('a').contents[0]
        player_name.append(name)
        team = player_soup.find('tbody').findAll('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Club'})[row].contents[0]
        club.append(team)
        pos = player_soup.find('tbody').findAll('td', attrs={'data-title': 'POS'})[row].contents[0]
        position.append(pos)
        goals = player_soup.find('tbody').findAll('td', attrs={'data-title': 'G' ,'class': 'responsive'})[row].contents[0]
        goals_scored.apppend(goals)
        a = player_soup.find('tbody').findAll('td', attrs={'data-title': 'A'})[row].contents[0]
        assists.append(a)
    except:
        pass    

player_data = {'player_name':player_name,
'club':club,
'position' : position,
'goals_scored' : goals_scored,
'assists' : assists,
 } 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player_data,orient='index')

df
```

The only thing I can figure out is that there is a slight difference in the HTML for the variables not returning data.  Do i need to include the class= responsive in my code?  If so, any examples of how that might look?

Position HTML :  F

Goals HTML:     11

Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this to get your desired data. I've only parsed the portion you needed. The rest you can do for dataframe. FYI, there are two types of classes attached to different td tags. `odd` and `even`. Don't forget to consider that as well.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_url = "https://www.mlssoccer.com/stats/season?page={0}&franchise=select&year=2017&season_type=REG&group=goals"
for url in [page_url.format(p) for p in range(5)]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
    table = soup.select("table")[0]
    for items in table.select(".odd,.even"):
        player = items.select("td[data-title='Player']")[0].text 
        club = items.select("td[data-title='Club']")[0].text
        position = items.select("td[data-title='POS']")[0].text
        goals = items.select("td[data-title='G']")[0].text
        assist = items.select("td[data-title='A']")[0].text
        print(player,club,position,goals,assist)
```

Partial result looks like:

```
Nemanja Nikolic CHI F 24 4
Diego Valeri POR M 21 11
Ola Kamara CLB F 18 3
```

As I've included both the classes in my script so you will get all data from that site.

Comment: Thanks for your input and time.  This works perfectly. I like how your solution condenses and simplified the code.  I wasn't aware of the issue with .odd and .even tags so thanks for the pointer!